# Jquery How to push the data, using find?

Tags: jquery

i have no.of `li` element which has the class name as `c_on`, i need to get all this `li`'s attribute and need to push in to array. for this, i did like this, but no result, any one know the good way to do this?

```
var pushEmpl = [];    
pushEmpl.push($('.demographics').find('ul.ocptn').find($('li.c_on')).each(function(){ return $(this).attr('data-ocp')}));
```

but it not getting the result. any other way to push this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to put the `push()` inside the `each()`.

```
var pushEmpl = []; 
$('.demographics').find('ul.ocptn').find($('li.c_on')).each(function(){ pushEmpl.push($(this).attr('data-ocp')); });
```

Comment: how to push only unique value? is there any way? (li.c_on unique values without repeating)

Comment: Use `.indexOf()` to check if the value is in the array already. For example `if(pushEmpl.indexOf($(this).attr('data-ocp')) == -1) { pushEmpl.push($(this).attr('data-ocp')); }` Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_indexof.htm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pushing from within the `.each()` function.

```
$('.demographics').find('ul.ocptn').find($('li.c_on')).each(function(){pushEmpl.push($(this).attr('data-ocp'))}));
```

Comment: how to push only unique value? is there any way? (li.c_on unique values without repeating)